# Multi factor authentication text message service

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am in new MFA, I am looking for text message service providers i saw MS Azure is providing that service not sure who else providing that service, Can any one tell me who is best text message provider for MFA security?

Thanks

Comment: Hi @BraveBoy, I think this question is [off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) because "*Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it.*".

Comment: i want your expert opinion what is the best and cheapest way to send sms from dotnet code to any cell carrier reliably.

Comment: What I was trying to say in my first comment was that it's not up to us to suggest a service for you - StackOverflow is for problem solving; once **you** have selected a service and have a specific problem implementing it, we will then help you. Your question as it is is off topic for that reason.

Comment: [Other questions which ask about sending texts in .net](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sms+.net) which have also been closed: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5467905/1364007), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/819134/1364007), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7582696/1364007), [4](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2380066/1364007), [5](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10782798/1364007). All closed as they are off topic. [**This one**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/526898/1364007) was not closed because it asks about a specific problem.